# Java program - Reading numeric data from txt file

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, text-files

This Java program is for finding the data from a txt file that consists a number of integers. I have figured out the codes for the maximum, average to run the program. For a lot of you it should be simple but I am relatively in-experienced in programming so bear with me.

---

There are three codes that I am having trouble are as follows.

1. number of numbers above average
2. number of prime numbers
3. finding the total sum

Does anyone know a way to do this?
Thanks. Any advice helps.

---

Here is the txt file sample of 20 numbers

1. 1
2. 12
3. 34
4. 54
5. 36
6. 76
7. 67
8. 86
9. 45
10. 44
11. 33
12. 22
13. 2
14. 4
15. 7
16. 87
17. 89
18. 99
19. 432
20. 543

List item

```
package Assignment1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Define two arrays - local variables
        // Declaring 10 integers
        int[] myIntArray = new int[20];
        // Declaring 10 strings

        //File
        File f = new File ("inputassignment1.txt");

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);    //Scanner
             for (int i=0; i < myIntArray.length; i++) {
                 myIntArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            // Closing the file
            sc.close();

       } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to create : "+e.getMessage());      
       }

        System.out.println("Highest number: " + maxNum(myIntArray));

        System.out.println("Average number: "+aveNum(myIntArray));
//      System.out.println(allNum(myIntArray));
    //  System.out.println(avgPlus(myIntArray));
    }// end of main
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I see you're reading in the numbers but you haven't tried doing anything with them so far.

Comment: you asked "does anyone know of a way to do this?" in Answer Yes I know of lots of ways.  But what have you tried and what are you stuck on

Comment: I figured out the max number which is:
public static int maxum(int[] MaxNum) {
      int Max = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < MaxNum.length; i++) {
           if (MaxNum[i] > Max) {
               Max = MaxNum[i];
         }
   }
   return Max;
}

Comment: Question edited: removed the beg for code. Come on now, none of this. You've got an answer already, work with it. If you don't understand the answer, ask them for clarification by commenting their answer. Also, please avoid posting code in comments as it won't be formatted properly and won't get the attention it deserves. Edit your question if you need to show us new code (but not to ask for others to provide you with code).

Comment: Sorry lads, I was unclear at the beginning and as I  have previously mentioned somewhere in the description. I am not very well experienced in programming especially Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break your task down:

There are 3 overall tasks:

1. Count how many numbers are above average
2. Find the total sum
3. Find all the prime numbers

Each of these requires you to:

- Read in numbers from a text file (into an array probably)
- Perform some checks on them (e.g. `if isPrime(number) { primes[numPrimes] = number; numPrimes++; }`)
- Count how many there are (`numNumbers++`, for each number)
- Sum them up (`totalSum += number`, for each number)

For the first one you will need to add another loop after you have the count/sum, the the other two should be doable by modifying the first loop (I have shown an example below).

I think you should be able to google for how to do each of those. Your code above looks like a good starting point.

```
int numNumbers = 0;
int totalSum = 0;
for (int i=0; i < myIntArray.length; i++) {
    myIntArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    numNumbers++;
    totalSum += myIntArray[i];
}
```